# how to get all the information of the same word

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a text in a .txt file  and there are some paragraphs,and you can see this structure:

```
name:zzzz,surnames:zzzz,id:zzzz,country:zzzz ...
name:zzzz,surnames:zzzz,id:zzzz,country:zzzz ...
name:zzzz,surnames:zzzz,id:zzzz,country:zzzz ...
name:zzzz,surnames:zzzz,id:zzzz,country:zzzz ...
```

And I would know how to compare all the 'id' and if there are paragrafs with the same id, eliminate one of them. Some idea? Thank you.

I have already gotten the first id :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the file path as parameter you can select the id for each line and save it on a dict.

```
import re
import sys

ref = dict()
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
       m = re.search(".*id:(\w*),", line)
       if m is not None and m.group(1) is not None:
           ref[m.group(1)] = line.strip()

for i in ref:
    print(ref[i])
```

Comment: Thank you! And if there are more than one line? Like:             
 "name:xxx, surnames:xxx, id:xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyyy           street:xxxxxxx yyyyyyyy"

Comment: Did you mean "name:xxx, sunames:xxx, id:xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyyy **,** street:xxxx. " ? If yes. You can use `m = re.search(".*id:([\w\s]*),", line)` to regexp get `\w` words and `\s` spaces, or `m = re.search(".*id:(.*),", line)` to get anything between _id:_ and _,_

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume your data looks like this.

```
name:z,surnames:zz,id:zzz,country:zzzz
name:y,surnames:yy,id:yyy,country:yyyy
name:x,surnames:xx,id:xxx,country:xxxx
name:z,surnames:zz,id:zzz,country:zzzz
```

I would suggest you use the `pandas` package and its `read_csv` function. It can give you an `DataFrame` object, which is convenient for dealing with data table.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(your_file_here, header=None, names=['name', 'surnames', 'id', 'country'])  # I am assuming you don't have header
temp = df[df.name == 'name:z'].iloc[0]  # save the first row with name:z
df_new = df[df.name != 'name:z']  # drop all rows with name z
df_new = df_new.append(temp)  # append the first row back
df_new.to_csv(new_file_name)  # if you want to save
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, create a dict of id's as you parse through the text file to keep track of which id's have been included. Write a new text file with only the unique id's as you parse through.

```
file = open("file.txt","r")
file_new = open("file_new.txt","w")
id_list = {}    

for line in file:
     #third value of the line is the id
     id = line.split(",")[2]

     #if id is new, we add its corresponding line to the new file and record
     if id not in id_list:
         id_list[id] = True
         file_new.write(line)
```